# How to ignore undefined variable error in PHP

Tags: php, linux

I recently setup a new web server and I'm getting undefined variable error.
If I use variables without initializing, it gives me an error.
The source code did not change. Only the LAMP environment did.
How would you solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Need to shut off/lower the error checking either in the php.ini or using [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) -- though you should be defining your variables before using them. ;p

Comment: See the correct answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71127489/388994

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well...

1. You should define all your variables, those warnings are there for a reason, to make you code better.  Undefined variables can easily lead to typo errors in variable names.
2. You can [change the *error_reporting* level](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php), above E_NOTICE to get rid of that, but it is highly unadvisable.

Answer (score 9):

you can change your error_reporting as people said, but if you want keep the default error_reporting configuration. you may use `@` operator. e.g: `@$post`

Comment: Downvotes because you told someone to use error suppression.

Comment: I give an alternative answer, as you can see in my begining of answer  I still suggest to use error_reporting

Comment: It doesn't deserve downvotes because I just learned something new from this :)

Comment: @RJFares Thanks.  :-)

Comment: On the other hand, I know there may be some null or undefined value, and I am going to handle it below, but I do not want to supress other warning that I have not handled. It looks so clumsy to make checking with ` if (!isset(...) || !isset(...))` but `if (!$var0 || !$var1)` looks much clearer

Answer (score 8):

You can set notices to not show.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE)
```

You should be developing with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)
```