# Can I hide PHP Warning: Undefined array key without suppressing all other warnings?

Tags: php, error-handling, warnings, isset

So, looks like they changed the way accessing an array with an unknown key raises a message.

```
<?php
if($myArray['foo']) { ... }
```

For 25 years this was simply raising a NOTICE, and people were quite happy to silence `E_NOTICE` in `php.ini`. With (I think) PhP 8.0 this raises now a WARNING.

For obvious reason I don't want to silence `E_WARNING`, so I (and all the rest of the world who for years used uninitialized variables as their value was simply `null`, like in so many other interpreted language) was looking for a possible way to get rid of warnings related to undefined variables/arrays/keys while keep reported all the other (more serious) programming error, like including a non existing file.

Reason behind this question is that I have to deal with tons of code written with above pattern in mind; I just can't rewrite it all, but still I need to switch to PhP 8, so no, I'm not asking how to use `isset()`.

Comment: I don't think so. There's no way to filter by specific types of messages, you just have the different error categories.

Comment: You might not be asking how to use `isset()`, but it is certainly one of the ways to professionally resolve your XY Problem.  PHP8 is helping developers to stop writing bad code for _another_ 25 years.

Comment: maybe consider not showing `ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');`, but logging errors. `ini_set('log_errors', 'On');`. log all: `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );`

Comment: @berend please reread the question title. Can I hide PHP Warning: Undefined array key **without suppressing all other warnings**?

Comment: The lesson is that you shouldn't have been ignoring the notices all this time either.

Comment: I am struggling to not hammer this question with: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5061432/2943403, https://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133/2943403, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1195549/2943403.  Equally, tempting is posting a two letter-answer: `No`.

Comment: This is why PHP should be abandoned as a language. PHP is constantly making backward incompatible changes and removing functions from the language that makes your code fail and have to be rewritten in newer versions of PHP. There's nothing wrong with deprecating language features that are problematic but removing them and creating errors and warnings where they didn't previously exist then forcing everyone onto it, that isn't how you keep your customers. Right now I'm dealing with old code that was written for PHP 5.x and doesn't work in PHP 5.6 let alone PHP 8

Comment: @PHPGuru completely agree. Newbie language, born newbie, kept newbie.

Comment: @PHPGuru and what upset me the most, is all these comments you can read here stating that it's your fault if you wrote unprofessional code. So, forgot one more: followed by newbies

Comment: @Jack I've been coding in PHP for a long time and I assure you there's nothing wrong with accessing an array key without checking for its existence first. In fact it's problematic to always be forced to use isset() empty() array_key_exists() and the new  null coalescing operator. In fact the new e_warning raised by this causes more problems than it solves. If people needed to check for misspellings of keys they could enable e_notice and the errors would show up that way. They didn't need to raise it to e_warning and break backwards compatibility. I'm really tired of PHP doing stuff like this.

Comment: @PHPGuru I've been using PHP since version 3, and abandoned it at version 6. Now I only use it for scripting and text file processing. It honestly deserves nothing more. I was already tired of some unique feature which clearly denoted an amateur design (one for all: ever noticed the incredible precedence for ternary operator (only php forces you to use parenthesis for ternary operator concatenation)?) ... Edit: looks like they realized of ternary stupidity and now it raises the "Unparenthesized" error.. AHhaah.. we're reaching Oracle level here

Comment: @Jack I think you mean version 7? PHP 6 doesn't exist. And yes around PHP 7 they required you to use parentheses with nested ternary operators, probably because it is left-associative rather than right-associative like other languages. Left-associative is of course less intuitive and so a mistake on PHP's part from the start. While I don't think they should raise an error, I agree that doing this without parentheses should be deprecated because of the counterintuitive nature of left-associative ternary operator.

Comment: @PHPGuru Correct, there is no point at all in having ternary left-associative, no other language does so. And yes sorry.. I meant the last version I used was PHP5.. I don't even know 6 didn't exist.

Comment: "2. Suppress the error with null coalescing operator for PHP 7+ (`$var ?? 'default'` )" is good: it is the same as using `isset($var)`. [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr/4261200#4261200)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can call the `set_error_handler` function and define a callback that bypasses that specific warning. When the callback returns true it won't trigger php error handling and will do nothing, in all other cases (return false) it will use the default error handling. See more here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

```
set_error_handler(function(int $errno, string $errstr) {
    if ((strpos($errstr, 'Undefined array key') === false) && (strpos($errstr, 'Undefined variable') === false)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, E_WARNING);
```

Be careful that some frameworks will call set_error_handler themselves and you can only have one error handler callback so it might always not work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use the [Error Suppression operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) `@`

```
<?php
if(@$myArray['foo']) { ... }
```

It's not as good as isset(), but at least it clearly says to the reader that you expect invalid indexes now and then.

Time has come to pay off your [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt).

Comment: Who says that accessing an undefined variable in PhP < 8 is a tech debt? Not testing the variable existence is a choice, if the language permits so.

Comment: @Jack yes, not testing the variable existence is an option, but you have to live with the consequences, which means notices or warnings.

Comment: So why judging other's work as technical debt? And for reference, it's my opinion that you shouldn't face any consequence when the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php]manual) for years states that **It is not necessary to initialize variables**. It is just another PhP result of its amateur design.

Comment: Also please note that reading an undefined variable is perfectly allowed in many script languages; can you image the next version of bash requiring you to declare variables before their usage? Half computers of the world wouldn't boot anymore

Comment: I can't believe this answer has been written in 2022

Comment: it should be `if($myArray['foo'] ?? false) { ... }` instead of `@` suppression

Comment: Don't use @ to suppress warnings. Suppress them in your php.ini file with error_reporting  = E_ALL & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT and write you code in such a way that anything that might throw a warning is handled by your code just like you would handle an exception. That's good design anyway.